# How to save response from view to the database in django

Tags: html, django

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from registeredmember.models import Registeredmember


# Create your models here.

class Carloan_form(models.Model):
    cost_of_vehicle_Naira               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    loan_repayment_tenure_Months        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    interest_rate_Percentage            = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    equity_contrib_rate_Percentage      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    depreciation_rate_Percentage        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    user                                = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    time                                = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.user)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from models import Carloan_form

class Carloan_formForm(ModelForm):
    cost_of_vehicle_Naira           = forms.DecimalField(label=(u'Cost of vehicle (in Naira)'))
    loan_repayment_tenure_Months    = forms.DecimalField(label=(u'Loan tenure (in Months)'))
    interest_rate_Percentage        = forms.DecimalField(label=(u'Interest rate (in %)'))
    equity_contrib_rate_Percentage  = forms.DecimalField(label=(u'Equity contribution rate (in %)'))
    depreciation_rate_Percentage    = forms.DecimalField(label=(u'Depreciation rate (in %)'))
    class Meta:
        model = Carloan_form
        exclude = ('user',)
```

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


from forms import Carloan_formForm
@login_required
def index(request):
    form = Carloan_formForm()
    if request.POST:
        form = Carloan_formForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            #Collection and Assignment of User input
            amount_of_vehicle = float(form.cleaned_data['cost_of_vehicle_Naira'])
            tenure = float(form.cleaned_data['loan_repayment_tenure_Months'])
            interest_rate = float(form.cleaned_data['interest_rate_Percentage'])
            equity = float(form.cleaned_data['equity_contrib_rate_Percentage'])
            depreciation_rate = float(form.cleaned_data['depreciation_rate_Percentage'])
            carloan = form.save(commit=False)
            carloan.user = request.user
            carloan.save()

            #Class Definition
            class LoanCalc:
                def __init__(self,amount_of_vehicle,tenure,interest_rate,equity,depreciation_rate):
                    self.amount_of_vehicle = amount_of_vehicle
                    self.tenure = tenure
                    self.interest_rate = interest_rate
                    self.equity = equity
                    self.depreciation_rate = depreciation_rate
                def interest(self):
                      return((self.interest_rate/100) * self.amount_of_vehicle *(self.tenure/12))
                def management_fee(self):
                    return 0.01 * (self.amount_of_vehicle + self.interest())
                def processing_fee(self):
                    return 0.0025 *(self.amount_of_vehicle + self.interest())
                def legal_fee(self):
                    return 0.0075 *(self.amount_of_vehicle + self.interest())
                def residual_amount(self):
                    return 0.01 * (self.amount_of_vehicle - ((self.depreciation_rate/100) * self.amount_of_vehicle *(self.tenure/12)))
                def equity_contribution(self):
                    return (self.equity/100) * self.amount_of_vehicle
                def total_amount(self):
                    return self.amount_of_vehicle+self.interest()+self.management_fee()+self.processing_fee()+self.legal_fee()+self.residual_amount() 
                def upfront_payment(self):
                    return self.management_fee() + self.processing_fee() + self.legal_fee() + self.equity_contribution() + self.residual_amount()
                def opening_balance(self):
                    return self.total_amount() - self.upfront_payment()
                def monthly_instalment(self):
                    return self.opening_balance()/self.tenure
                def LoanPaymentPlan(self):
                    months = 1
                    total_amount = self.amount_of_vehicle+self.interest()+self.management_fee()+self.processing_fee()+self.legal_fee()+self.residual_amount()
                    upfront_payment = self.management_fee()+self.processing_fee()+self.legal_fee()+self.equity_contribution()+self.residual_amount()
                    opening_balance = total_amount - upfront_payment
                    balance = opening_balance
                    while months <= self.tenure:
                        if balance > 0:
                            monthly_instalment =(opening_balance/self.tenure)
                            monthly_interest = (((self.interest_rate/100) * balance)/ 12)
                            loan_payment = monthly_instalment - monthly_interest
                            closing_balance = balance - monthly_instalment
                            print '  ',months,'  ',round(balance,2),'   ', round(monthly_instalment,2),'        ',round(monthly_interest,2) \
                            , '       ',' ',round(loan_payment,2),'     ',round(closing_balance,2)
                            balance = closing_balance
                            months += 1
                    return 'Thank you for using the Loan Calc App'

            #Creation of an instance with the name 'calc'
            calc = LoanCalc(amount_of_vehicle,tenure,interest_rate,equity,depreciation_rate)
            amountofVehicle = amount_of_vehicle
            interest = calc.interest()
            managementFee = calc.management_fee()
            processingFee = calc.processing_fee()
            legalFee = calc.legal_fee()
            residualAmount = calc.residual_amount()
            equityContribution = calc.equity_contribution()
            totalAmount = calc.total_amount()
            upfrontPayment = calc.upfront_payment()
            openingBalance = calc.opening_balance()
            loanpaymentplan =calc.LoanPaymentPlan()



            #An empty form to be displayed alongside the result
            forms = Carloan_formForm()

            #Renders a template that displays the result
            return render_to_response('carloan/result.html', {'form': forms, 'result':amountofVehicle , 'result1': interest, 'result2': managementFee, 'result3': processingFee,
                                                              'result4': legalFee, 'result5': residualAmount, 'result6': equityContribution, 'result7': totalAmount,
                                                              'result8': upfrontPayment, 'result9':openingBalance, 'result10': loanpaymentplan},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    #If the user doesn't submit the form, it displays an empty form
    else:
        form = Carloan_formForm()
    #Rendering a that template that displays an empty form
    return render_to_response('carloan/index.html', {'form': form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## My questions are;

1. Is there a way i can save the results am passing to the template?
2. Is there a way i can send the results that i have saved in Q1. above, and send it to the user through email(only when the user wants it)?

3.'result10': loanpaymentplan` that i am passing to the template, only prints one line and doesn't go through the loop and print everything but meanwhile it prints everything in the command prompt(still in development). What could be wrong?

Comment: 1. Please fix your indentation. 2. What does "When I call on this ['result10': loanpaymentplan]" mean? I have no idea. 3. What does your question title have to do with any of the 4 actual questions you ask?

Comment: The big gain here is merging Carloan_form and LoanCalc, it resolves the  redundancy and your need to save the results, as they will be available to you whenever you retrieve a record. For emailing on demand you could save `calc.pk` in `request.SESSION` or return it with the result in a form. Another view with `@login_required` could match a given pk with the authenticating user. If all is well, you fetch the record and email it as shown in my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Jesse the Game. Could you please go a step further by giving me a skeletal code like the ones below to buttress the useful points you have just mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at something like this:

**The model**

```
from django.db import models
class LoanCalc(models.Model):
    amount_of_vehicle = models.DecimalField()
    tenure = models.DecimalField()
    interest_rate = models.DecimalField()
    equity = models.DecimalField()
    depreciation_rate = models.DecimalField()

    def interest(self):
        return((self.interest_rate/100) * self.amount_of_vehicle *(self.tenure/12))
    def management_fee(self):
        return 0.01 * (self.amount_of_vehicle + self.interest())
```

**The view**

```
# views.py
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

from .models import LoanCalc

def loan_calc(request, **kwargs):
    calc = LoanCalc.objects.create(**kwargs)

    # Render your calc model in a template and use send_mail to email it
    send_mail(
        'This is your loan calculation!',
        get_template('carloan/email.txt').render(
            Context({
                'calc': calc,
            })
        ),
        'you@example.com',
        ['receiver@gexample.com']
    )

    return render_to_response('carloan/result.html',
                              {'form': forms, 'calc': calc}
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**The view template**

```
# result.html
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Interest</td>
       <td>{{ calc.interest }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Management fee</td>
       <td>{{ calc.management_fee }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**The email template**

```
# email.txt
Hi, this is your loan calculation overview:

Interest: {{ calc.interest }}
Management fee: {{ calc.management_fee }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.Am not very sure if this is what am looking for but it is a giant step forward for me and i will try to customize it. Perhaps i should paste my models.py forms.py and views.py. Also, i think the send_email you have there is automatic. I want a situation whereby it would be at the user's discretion.

Comment: Please check the op, its much better now